# как вывести эти данные из firebase? Они добавляются с помощью List из android , мне нужно вывести их

Tags: android, firebase-database

Нужно вывести results

"[image: firebase]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать так. Пропишите путь к нужным данным, а затем, добравшись до `results`, получите нужные данные, проходя по всем данным, которые в нем лежат.

**UPDATE**
Чтобы собрать все данные из всех нижележащих узлов `results`, можно объявить `ArrayList` и записывать полученные строки в него.

```
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
private ArrayList<String> list;
private String currentUserId = "ID пользователя, чьи результаты Вы хотите получить";
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
mDatabase.child("Users").child(currentUserId).child("results").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.e("firebase", "Ошибка при получении данных", task.getException());
        }
        else {
            list = new ArrayList<String>();
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
            for (DataSnapshot dschild : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                String str0 = dschild.child("0").getValue().toString(); //строка 0
                String str1 = dschild.child("1").getValue().toString(); //строка 1
                        list.add(str0);
                        list.add(str1);
            }
        }           
    }
});
```

Comment: Так он выводит только результат одного теста, а мне надо нескольких, как сделать можно? Можно ли как-то в List загнать или сразу получить List с результатами?

Comment: Добавила в код запись в List, если правильно поняла Ваше сообщение

Comment: Если мой ответ решил Ваш вопрос, его можно отметить как принятый, нажав на галочку слева от него.